# Associating SpeechRecognizer with Specific Microphone

Tags: c#, uwp, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am using the **SpeechRecognizer** class from the **Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition** namespace.

I want the user to be able to select their preferred audio capture device from a ComboBox which I populate as follows...

```
foreach (var device in await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(MediaDevice.GetAudioCaptureSelector()))
{
    microphoneCombo.Items.Add(device);
}
```

How can I associate the recognizer object with the selected audio capture device?

I am familiar with classes like **MediaCaptureInitializationSettings** and **MediaCapture** but when it comes to associating SpeechRecognizer with a specific device, I am hitting a brick wall.

Any advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get a voice input device plugged on your pc, you will get an popup to determine the device type of this device, which means the primary voice device is managed by user through system.

Currently there is an [Audio Graph](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/audio-graphs) API that supports audio routing with user specified device. But it can't be intergrated with SpeechRecognizer.
And for SpeechRecognizer there is also no way to specify input device.

Welcome to submit your feedback to Microsoft through windows Feedback app.